# How to apply a basic bootstrap style like in the Laravel 5 tutorial?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel. Installed Laravel 5 on my windows 7, along with wamp. started following the intermediate task tutorial on Laravel doc (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart-intermediate). The tutorial shows a neat screenshot of what the tutirial UI looks like and they mention they applied basic bootstrap style. They didn't explain that part. How do I do it? my UI looks so basic without any styling even if I followed the same tutorial and have style names all over the views.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include bootstrap.css in the head section of your blade file.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm new to css in its modern form. I used a few simple styles a few years ago when I had to do simple html with php. But looking at all this evolution I'm overwhelmed. If I wanted to customize this basic bootstrap style to my color/font/etc. preferences, where do I start?

Comment: If you want to customize bootstrap as a theme, for bootstrap3 (current stable version), you need to learn "less" and configure its variables and compile them. If yoı are a beginner, you can start with bootstrap4 which used "sass" for its customization. Also you can check bootswatch.com for ready themes.